# Data Set that can be used for statistics

Tags: statistics, dataset, google-visualization, data-visualization

I need some raw data to visualize it with google charts and some other APIs. Problem is that i some raw data that includes timestamps too.
For example visitors visiting a website i.e. from which device `(mobile/computer etc)` they accessed website, at what time `(hours:minutes:second:miliseconds)` and what which links they visited etc. Please help me to know if someone knows about such kind of dummy raw data on web.

Comment: I want to add example of it i.e. Hits on WikiPedia, from which type of device and at what time

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own dataset using Google Spreadsheets. 
For example, consider the spreadsheet from the link below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aj9J3uCNjN9_dG1rdmNtTlhyNWpkTUVHVHBwRzNWX2c&output=html

If you tweak the link, it can provide you with the JSON representation of the data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0Aj9J3uCNjN9_dG1rdmNtTlhyNWpkTUVHVHBwRzNWX2c&pub1

Basically, what you have to do in order to get the JSON response is replace the "pub" element to "tq" and remove the "output=html" element at the end adding "pub1" instead.

With this procedure you should be able to create your own datasource for your tests.
You can find more information on the Google Chart API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

Hope it helps